# Getting MD5 Hash of File from URL

Tags: java, android, md5

The result I'm getting is that files of the same type are returning the same md5 hash value.  For example two different jpgs are giving me the same result.  However, a jpg vs a apk are giving different results.

Here is my code...

```
public static String checkHashURL(String input) {
    try {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        InputStream is = new URL(input).openStream();

        try {
            is = new DigestInputStream(is, md);

            int b;

            while ((b = is.read()) > 0) {
                ;
            }
        } finally {
            is.close();
        }
        byte[] digest = md.digest();
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        for (int i = 0; i < digest.length; i++) {
            sb.append(
                    Integer.toString((digest[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(
                            1));
        }
        return sb.toString();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure are hashing jpg files instead of a 404-error vs. DNS-not found error?

Comment: My guess would be that only the header tags of the file data is being read and hashed, therefore causing files of similar types to appear equal.  I recommend debugging the data being read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is broken:

```
while ((b = is.read()) > 0)
```

Your code will stop at the first byte of the stream which is 0. If the two files have the same values before the first 0 byte, you'll fail. If you *really* want to call the byte-at-a-time version of `read`, you want:

```
while (is.read() != -1) {}
```

The [parameterless `InputStream.read()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28%29) method returns -1 when it reaches the end of the stream.

(There's no need to assign a value to `b`, as you're not using it.)

Better would be to read a buffer at a time:

```
byte[] ignoredBuffer = new byte[8 * 1024]; // Up to 8K per read
while (is.read(ignoredBuffer) > 0) {}
```

This time the condition is valid, because [`InputStream.read(byte[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28byte%5B%5D%29) would only ever return 0 if you pass in an empty buffer. Otherwise, it will try to read at least one byte, returning the length of data read or -1 if the end of the stream has been reached.

Comment: @user1288686: Has it actually fixed the problem though? :)

Comment: yes it has.  One more question.. since i'm reading the file byte by byte, will this take up the same amount of bandwidth as say downloading the file?  I'm wondering because I'm developing this to verify downloaded updates to my android application and am limited by bandwidth restrictions by the carriers.

Comment: @user1288686: Whether you read it byte by byte or a buffer at a time, you're still fetching the whole file, so yes. It *is* downloading the file, it's just not saving it to disk.